# Need to make kit of 32 small rust programs in a folder, but each must be able to be compiled individually by users in their environment

Tags: c, rust, rust-cargo

Say, if I have a kit of tool001,...tool47, each of which uses regular expression as a small but vital part of it, but each one needs to be compiled NOT in a set, but individually at the whim of one of my several hundred users.  I CANNOT deliver this if they cannot be simply compiled one only by choice.  But, it looks like this is a function that the rust environment goes out of its way to make impossible.  I can rustc compile a simple file, but not one including regex. I have been working off an example from this document segment https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/, which appears as follows:

```
--------
    use regex::Regex;

fn main() {
    let re = Regex::new(r"Hello (?<name>\w+)!").unwrap();
    let Some(caps) = re.captures("Hello Murphy!") else {
        println!("no match!");
        return;
    };
    println!("The name is: {}", &caps["name"]);
}
----snip---
The diagnostic message I get is:

$ rustc try_regex3.rs 
error[E0432]: unresolved import `regex`
 --> try_regex3.rs:1:5
  |
1 | use regex::Regex;
  |     ^^^^^ maybe a missing crate `regex`?
  |
  = help: consider adding `extern crate regex` to use the `regex` crate

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0432`.
```

I did not see a solution in E0432.

I apologize if I am missing something that is obvious, but I cannot see it, and without a simple solution, I need to just build the tools in C.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you want to make 32 tools for users to use but these tools need to be abled to be compiled by users?

If this is correct then the users would need rustc or cargo there is no way around this unless you change how your programs work.

as for the error this is likely because you do not have regex added as a libary if you do not already have rustup or cargo installed I highly recommend installing [rustup](https://rustup.rs/) this allows for much easier control of your environment, you can then use `cargo new project_name` to make a project and from their you can add your code inside of `main.rs` and inside of `cargo.toml` add a line that says [dependencies] then under that you can add any libraries you want with the syntax    name = "version"  for example   regex = "1.10.2"

Comment: It appeard rustup was ONLY for windows.  I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.  Rustc would be fine, but I am unable to see how to specify the crate I've added by cargo using rustc.  What is wanted is a situation where the source files are there, and with a single, simple, easily auditable command, on whatever platform installed, the user can just compile her choice of a tool, one only, and use it.  Any reasonable way to do that after any reasonable setup, including setup using cargo, would be fine, but it needs to be one tool compiled only out fo the pool

Comment: Yes, sorry, I did see the thing about the src/main.rs directory, and I can copy tooln.rs into src/main.rs then copy the binary back out again, if I had to.  Why?  Why Is That Necessary?  What is this convoluded infrastructure requirement accomplishing?  Why is there not  simple solution to such a simple task?

Comment: you can install rustup on linux after installing curl here is a tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8TBvvm3T53Y&ab_channel=SavvyNik    in the next one he also shows how to use cargo if you would like to watch that, as for the actual program this is just not possible to compile unless if the user has rustc or cargo (you could possibly contain all rustc versions for different OS's and make the main.rs abled to compile the other ones but things would get complicated) I would recomend you maybe have one program that can download one of the other programs from a github repo if this is suitable

Comment: @user3713271 I suspect cargo is implemented the way it is to support large projects, and noone has spent their time to add any code to support your more narrow usecase. What advantage is there to a package manager and project managment tool to support building a single  rust file in a random directory  ? Whatever reasoning someone made to make strict rules about the input and outputs cargo will handle isn't going to change much, it still can't do it your way.

Comment: If you mean that the user is supposed to have cargo downloaded you could then make the main.rs of one of your cargo projects compile the other ones using std::process::Command    you could have all projects in one main directory and from the main project you could then run something like "cd .. && cd /tool1 && cargo build" using std::proccess::command to jump back into another project and build it, from there you can extract the program from the build dir and place it wherever you want, yes its a little bit confusing but cargo is made to simplify more large projects that rely on each other

Comment: It is at least helpful to see I have not missed anything.  Please accept my thanks for these answers.  I will reassess now the best I can.  Thanks to those below too.  Looks like two sets of answers.

Comment: @user3713271 if you want to only use rustc things will get messy really quickly, but I think its possible through this command you would have to download the dependency from github and do something like rustc main.rs -L dependency=path/to/regex     im not totally sure on the syntax

Answer (score 0):

`rustc` needs to be told on the command line to use the regex crate.

Or just use `cargo` like you're meant to. You can have many binaries from a single source tree without even using workspaces, just by specifying [multiple binaries](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/cargo-targets.html#binaries) with the `[[bin]]` option. You can then build them individually with `cargo build --bin the-binary`.

Comment: So the binary must be added with cargo, but cargo won't allow me to compile the individual file by name.  I am not seeing a cargo qualifier to show where it puts its binaries.  Something like that would be necessary to program a Bash script for this.

Comment: What advantage is there to not allowing users to compile files individually like this?  There must be some rationale for it, right?  Why are you "supposed to" do it that way?

Comment: TIP: You don't need `[[bin]]` if they are put in a `bin/` directory.

Comment: cargo will use the CARGO_TARGET_DIR env variable if you need to put binaries another place than the default. You can reach your objectives by creating tool001/src/main.rs , tool002/src/main.rs and so on, within each toolxxx/ you run cargo init && cargo add regex. Now you're set and can go into each toolxxx folder and run cargo build, or your own shell script that provides arguments etc. If it's impossible for you to name the source file toolxxx/src/main.rs , it's best to tell us what your possibilities are - but trying to do something that cargo doesn't implement is rather counterproductive

Comment: I do NOT need a different place.  In fact, for this client, the default would be the most transparent and acceptable.  However, I did find the ~/.cargo has binaries in it, but I tried this as the path for both rust --crate and cargo build --bin and both of these fail.

Comment: Sorry, I do not want to be counter-productive.  If there is not a normal simple answer to compiling a single file.  The tooln/src/main.rs should work.  Thank you.  Please though, can anyone explain why this build system is so restricted like this?

Comment: @user3713271 note that `cargo install --bin toolXX` will compile `toolXX` and install it to `~/.cargo`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I see the problem. Simply arrange your source code like this:

```
./
|- Cargo.toml
`- src/
   `- bin/
      |- tool01.rs
      |- tool02.rs
      …
```

Add `regex` as a dependency to `Cargo.toml`, then run `cargo install --bin toolXX` to build just `toolXX` from `bin/toolXX.rs` and install it to `~/.cargo/bin`